# d3 pie chart with flask server

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, d3.js

I'm using the built-in flask server and I want to show an animated pie chart, like here:
http://codepen.io/tpalmer/pen/jqlFG 
or
http://jsfiddle.net/thmain/xL48ru9k/1/

For simplicity, I use the latter one.

The python flask server code is:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash
from forms import ContactForm
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'blah'

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
   return render_template('test.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)
```

I did copy the javascript code provided on the webpage to the file static/script2.js
and the css code to static/css/style_d3.css

My HTML code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link  rel="stylesheet"  href="//style_d3.css" type="text/css">
  </head>

  <body>
<p>test</p>
<div class="animated-ring">
    <svg></svg>
</div>

    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//script2.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

I run the webpage through the flask server. But I get a webpage that just says "test", there's no chart.
What do I do wrong?

I'd really appreciate if someone could help me.

Comment: I did replace the //script2.js and same for css with a full http link and uploaded them there, now it works.

So the problem is really: how can I get flask server to load the js and css files?

Answer (score 0):

You only render the test.html at "/" path, the script2.js needs to be rendered too at "/script2.js".

Try this one liner at your project's root directory to host all files:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but that didn't do the job.
that way the flask server doesn't run anymore, or does it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set to a path your js file. In your app dir create a static folder then put your script2.js file and when you call this file at html use flask url_for() function

```
src="{{url_for('static', filename='script2.js'}}"
```